# Yii ListView Pagination: Scroll to Top

Tags: javascript, pagination, scroll, yii

I'm currently using the `zii.widgets.CBaseListView` on a long list of items. The list is long enough that it causes the page to scroll.

When I use the Yii pager at the bottom of the list to go to Page 2, the browser window keeps it's scroll position rather than bouncing to the top of the next list.

Anybody have an easy solution to this issue? I have this implemented in a number of places on this project. I've poured through the documentation and I'm coming up empty.

Answer (score 6):

Here is enhanced solution of Alex Kliuchnikau.
I also created an anchor right before including ClistView widget and then in CListView settings I used '[afterAjaxUpdate](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#afterAjaxUpdate-detail)' property.

```
<a id="scrollTop"></a>
<?php 

$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'function(){
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#scrollTop").position().top }, 100);}'

));

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set **'ajaxUpdate' => false** in CListView property.

Comment: So there's no way to have ajax page updating and use Javascript or page anchors to scroll back to the top of the list? This seems like a pretty huge usability oversight in the paging feature.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I managed to scroll to the top using JQuery.

I created an anchor point at the top of the page with `id=scrollTopPosition`.

Page will scroll to top on user click (actually, mouseup) on the pager (with ID `'yw1'`,  check with Firebug)

```
$('#yw1 > li').live('mouseup',function() { //mouseup to avoid conflict with request

   topoflist=$('#scrollTopPosition').position();
   thetop=topoflist.top-250;    
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:thetop}, 0);} 
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

For all YiiPagers with animation and without anchor. Just scroll top:

```
$('.yiiPager > li > a').live('mouseup', function () {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 150);
});
```